# Google App Script - Regex - SyntaxError: Invalid quantifier Error

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

Trying to filter gmail messages with certain phrases in email body. My input for search terms is as below.  Not sure using **\W** is correct.

> (?i)(\W|^)(program instance status: Error|program instance status: Skipped |program instance status: Long\srunning | program instance status:Stopped | program instance status: Cancelled | Program Status = Error|Program Status = Skipped |Program Status = Long\srunning | Program Status =Stopped | Program Status = Cancelled | Status: Error|Status: Skipped |Status: Long\srunning | Status:Stopped | Status: Cancelled |program status: Scheduled | program status: Paused | program status: Awaiting\sTriggered | program status: Ready | progam status: Active | program status: Inactive)(\W|$)(\W|^)(program instance status: Error | program instance status:
>   Skipped | program instance status: Long\srunning | program instance
>   status:Stopped | program instance status: Cancelled | Program Status =
>   Error | Program Status = Skipped | Program Status = Long\srunning |
>   Program Status = Stopped | Program Status = Cancelled | Status: Error
>   | Status: Skipped | Status: Long\srunning | Status: Stopped | Status:
>   Cancelled |program status: Scheduled | program status: Paused |
>   program status: Awaiting\sTriggered | program status: Ready | progam
>   status: Active | program status: Inactive)(\W|$)

When I run the script. I get ***SyntaxError: Invalid quantifier Error***

The code I'm using is:

```
 var mFrom = sheet.getRange("J2").getValue();
 var notinSubject = sheet.getRange("K2").getValue();
 var input= sheet.getRange("I2").getValue();
 var keyWord = sheet.getRange("L2").getValue();
 var casebyWho = sheet.getRange("M2").getValue();

 var pafcSearchQuery = "from:"+mFrom+" before:"+nextDate+"after:"+theDate+ 
 "-subject: "+notinSubject+ " -is:sent ";
  Logger.log(pafcSearchQuery);
  var threads = GmailApp.search(pafcSearchQuery, 0, 500);

 Logger.log(input);
 for(var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
   // Utilities.sleep(1000);

    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      var msg = messages[m].getBody();
      if (msg.search(input) !== -1) {

      yCount = yCount + threads[i].getMessageCount();
     }
  }
}
sheet.appendRow([labelName,yCount]);
```

I'm not well versed in Regex usage. Any nudge or suggestions towards the right direction will be helpful.

I had used the regex based on an example from Examples of regular expressions from G Suite Admin help page https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417?hl=en

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this the exact code you are using?

Comment: If so, then I think you have to escape the inner quotation marks on the first line as follows: `" before:"2018-12-20" after` get to `" before:\"2018-12-20\" after` (note the backslash before the inner quotation marks). You also have to do this for the after filter. Additionally you are then missing a quotation mark at the end so it has to be `-is:sent";`.

Comment: @cramopy actually the code I use is  "var pafcSearchQuery = "from:"+mFrom+" before:"+nextDate+" after:"+theDate+ "-subject: "+notinSubject+ " -is:sent ";  Updated the sample as the same now. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: The pattern is "corrupt" since there is `(\W|$)(\W|^)` in the pattern. Make sure the pattern is like `(?i)(\W|^)(alt1|alt2|...|altN)(\W|$)`

Comment: It is still uclear from your code what is wrong. Generally, the issue appears when there is  something like `{1,3}+`, `(+|abc)`, `^+abc$`, i.e. when you try to quantifier a start of a pattern delimiter or a quantifier. This is often a result of the regex escaping failure, when `"\+"` is used instead of `"\\+"` in JS code.

Comment: @TheMasterI get the same input as I have shown above in the Log

Answer (score 0):

Your regex starts a mode modifier for case-insensitivity: `(?i)`.  This causes an error in Google Apps Script because [JavaScript does not support regex mode modifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

Instead, you can make your regex case-insensitive by setting the `i` flag like this: 
`/YOUR_REGEX/i`.

Or when defining your regex based on an input string (as in your case), you'd do it like this:
`new RegExp( YOUR_REGEX_STRING, 'i' )`.